# How to Continue bulk inserts when exception occurs

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jpa, try-catch

I am using jpa with hibernate I want to insert 100 record in Database, suppose I get  exception   JDBC batch update in 50th record insertion i need to handling the Exception and I need to persist remaining record to DB.

Code:

```
 private List<TempCustomers> tempCustomer =new ArrayList<TempCustomers>();

    public String migrateCustomers() {

      TempCustomers temp = null;
        for(DoTempCustomers tempCustomers:doTempCustomers){

              try {
                temp=new TempCustomers();
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(temp, tempCustomers);
                        tempCustomer.add(temp);
                    entityManager.persist(temp);


              }catch (Exception e) {
                  tempCustomer.add(temp);
                  entityManager.persist(temp);
                  log.info("Exception ..."+e);
                  return "null";
              }
        }


        return "null";
    }
```

Comment: thank you for responding,suppose reading 100 record from List , then i will persist using the entityManager.persist(temp) ..in that list one record is not proper so hibernate through the JDBC Batch Exception .that time reaming 99 record i want to store database ,how can i do It?

Comment: yes ..Ras,i need to catch exception and reaming to persist .How can do it?

Comment: Never do this `log.info("Exception ..."+e);` ... it swallows the stack trace. Instead, use `log.info("Exception ...",e);` with the exception as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Nagendra.

What Mr. RAS is telling is correct.

For example you are persisting 100 entities and exception happened in the 50th Entity persist. You have exception handler it will work for you to handle the situation. It ll skip the current one and process the next one.

Things to take care as follows:

1- Your exception handling should be within the loop, hope you already have it.

2- For exception you can save the entity in different list for further analysis for error details. do it in the exception catch block.

3- I am not sure whether you are using the transaction manager or not, transaction need to take care.

--

Comment: Rudra how can i achieve second case,by above code tempCustomer list added to entity objec(temp),it give exception only when entityManager.persist(temp) statement ,can you make sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd case please remove the line...

entityManager.persist(temp);

as you already know this throws exception. keep it in the list for your further analysis. better put into any queue(ActiveMQ) upto you.

Best solution for this is again:

Validate all your data before persist...to minimize the exception. runtime things need your re-processing again and that should be manual.

Comment: As a warning, do not use footers that link to your website, or your answers may be flagged as spam.